# How do I create a lazy Future in Python (asyncio) that can be kicked off after creation?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to wrap my head around `asyncio` in Python. I wrote this little programm that when invoked will first print

> Server booting
>
> Do stuff called

and then after one second

> Async Thingy

That is exactly what it is supposed to do but it's not quite the way I want it yet.

Basically this mimics a `Server` that wants to create a `PeerPool` in `__init__` which depends on `ThingThatWeAreWaitingOn`. I want to be able to create the `PeerPool` in `__init__` and pass an `Awaitable[ThingThatWeAreWaitingOn]` that the `PeerPool` can use as soon as it is ready. Again, this seems to work just fine but the catch is, as the code stands now, we kick off the task to resolve `ThingThatWeAreWaitingOn` directly from within `__init__` but ideally I'd like to be able to kick that off from within `run()`.

How would I do that?

```
import asyncio
from typing import (
    Awaitable,
    Any
)

class ThingThatWeAreWaitingOn():
    name = "Async Thingy"

class PeerPool():

    def __init__(self, discovery: Awaitable[ThingThatWeAreWaitingOn]):
        self.awaitable_discovery = discovery

    def do_stuff(self):
        print("Do stuff called")
        self.awaitable_discovery.add_done_callback(lambda d: print(d.result().name))

class Server():

    def __init__(self):
        # This immediately kicks of the async task but all I want is to 
        # create a Future to pass that would ideally be kicked off in
        # the run() method
        self.fut_discovery = asyncio.ensure_future(self.get_discovery())
        self.peer_pool = PeerPool(self.fut_discovery)
    
    async def get_discovery(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return ThingThatWeAreWaitingOn()

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        print("Server booting")

        # Here is where I want to "kick off" the self.fut_discovery but how?
        # self.fut_discovery.kick_off_now()

        self.peer_pool.do_stuff()

        loop.run_forever()

server = Server()
server.run()
```

Here's a link to a runnable demo: https://repl.it/repls/PleasedHeavenlyLock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand everything right, you want something like this:

```
class Server():    
    def __init__(self):
        self.fut_discovery = asyncio.Future()
        self.peer_pool = PeerPool(self.fut_discovery)

    async def get_discovery(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return ThingThatWeAreWaitingOn()

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        print("Server booting")

        async def discovery_done():
            res = await self.get_discovery()
            self.fut_discovery.set_result(res)
        asyncio.ensure_future(discovery_done())  # kick discovery to be done

        self.peer_pool.do_stuff()
        loop.run_forever()
```

---

You may want to rewrite code somehow to make in clearer. Right now it's not very clear what you're going to do and which part of code depends of which.

For example, `awaitable_discovery` name is misleading: plain awaitable not necessary has `add_done_callback` method. If you're planing to use this method, signature

```
class PeerPool():
    def __init__(self, fut_discovery: asyncio.Future):
```

will make more sense.

May be you should create class for discovery. You can inherit `asyncio.Future` or implement `__await__` [magic method](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression) to make it's objects future-like/awaitable.

Comment: Could anyone provide a hint if is it possible to do without Futures, in Curio/Trio style?

Comment: @AndriyMaletsky If you just dislike the term "future", you can always use `asyncio.Event` to signal that something happened (but a future is slightly more lightweight). Also, to add a coroutine to the event loop, one should use `loop.create_task` rather than `ensure_future` ([explanation](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555)).

Comment: @AndriyMaletsky To add to the above, in asyncio futures are not something to avoid or somehow consider bad in any way. A future is an _interface_ (task is the actual class) that allows access to something that will happen using both `await` and classical callbacks. This is extremely useful for connecting asyncio to legacy callback-based systems (and for implementing asyncio itself).